# Ubuntu boots up super zoomed in - persists through reboot [Solved]

Tags: display, display-resolution, xrandr, gpu

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XrWD.jpg

The login screen looks totally normal, but after logging in its zoomed in the amount seen in the picture. I didn't install or update anything that I'm aware of. Before logging in when I can clearly see the settings, I can see that zoomed in feature is not selected.

Any advice on how to fix this would be appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, you can answer your own question, if you don't mind move the answer part into the answer form.

Answer (score 0):

Issue was fixed using this:

dconf reset -f /

Resets quite a few things, so I would only recommend using as a last resort